# Geometry is making TOC start on even page/page ii

Tags: table-of-contents, geometry

I'm doing something wrong with `geometry` and now my Table of Content is not starting on page `i` -- and yes, I want two blank  pages to appear before the title page. In other word, the only thing wrong with the following is that the TOC starts one page too late (an even page).

Thank you.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft} % Customization of TOC LOF LOT
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks

\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\clearpage
~
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\newgeometry{
    tmargin  =30mm,
    bmargin  =30mm,
    lmargin  =35mm,
    rmargin  =35mm,
    headsep  =0.5cm,
    footskip =1cm,
    columnsep=.3cm,
    headheight=.5cm
}
\begin{titlepage}
    \textbf{TITLE PAGE}
    %\end{mypar}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\frontmatter
{
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=black,
        linktoc=page
    }\textbf{}
\tableofcontents
}

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}

\listoftables
\clearpage
\onecolumn

\section{Preface}
    The information herein is the original text.
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
    A detailed description.
\twocolumn
\clearpage

\mainmatter

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have add `\textbf{}` just before `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Don't hesitate to write something a like a "full reply" for me to give you the solution solved tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `\textbf{}` just before `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\textbf{}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```